# how to create a bootstrap tooltipto display different amounts in table?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

Suppose I have a table which displays rows of data from a backend service like this:

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="item in rows">
        <td>
                <span>
                    {{item.amount}}
                </span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

How can I define a BS3 tooltip to display item.otheramount when hovering over it?

Comment: Can you provide your custom filter so I can check it?

Answer (score 0):

Just add `tooltip="{{item.otheramount}}"` next to `ng-repeat` or wherever you want to put it.

**E.g.**

`<tr ng-repeat="item in rows" tooltip="{{item.otheramount}}">`

Hope it helps.

Comment: I forgot to mention I have a filter too: {{item.otheramount | mycustomfilter }} but this does not work?

Comment: Can you provide your custom filter so I can check it?